# Kkeyboard event for Control or Shift key pressed alone?

Tags: glut

Nor `KeyboardFunc` no `SpecialFunc` will detect those keys: Control, Alt, Shift, Caps. (Maybe few others, Win, Fn, etc). How to detect a press and release of ANY physically present button onakeyboard? Or at least those most popular like Shift and Control (when they are pressed alone).

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out  [alternative glut libraries](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/)

For example [FreeGlut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net)[*] has a [glutSpecialFunc()](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#WindowCallback) that might suit your needs

[*] First one I looked at

Comment: No, FreeGLUT's glutSpecialFunc() does the same thing as the original GLUT's. It reacts to F1~F12, page up/down, home/end, insert key, arrow keys, but NOT modifier keys like ctrl, alt, or shift.